# Copy every file with a certain extension (recursive)

Tags: linux

I need a script (may it be bash, ksh, or whatever) which copies, for backup purposes, all the sub-directories and files of a directory: .znc - but .log files.

The structure is like this:

> .znc/users 
>   .znc/users/*username*/moddata/
>   .znc/users/*username*/moddata/log
>   .znc/users/*username*/moddata/log/*files*.log
>   .znc/users/*username2*/moddata/
>   .znc/users/*username2*/moddata/log
>   .znc/users/*username2*/moddata/log/*files*.log

Note that this is only part of the structure, but this is the part I am having trouble with.

I need to copy all the content of .znc/ but files which extension is "log".
I haven't been able to do much with `find` or `grep`, because there is a variable, username.

Comment: Why not grep for `.log`? It might have issues if that is part of a filename, but that should not generally be the case.

Comment: For backups, you can use [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) which is built around [rsync](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rsync](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html). It also has the nice feature that it preserves owner/group/perms etc

```
rsync -avi --exclude '*.log' .znc/ /path/to/destination/directory/
```

Comment: You're welcome. You should also look at [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/), which uses rsync and which is very useful for backups. It's also easy to set up

Comment: In this case I use dropbox for backups, since it's a very little amount of data and I don't need frequent backups because of the nature of the program, it's useful to have around different servers live. I will look into rsnapshot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

```
cd /to/top/of/dir/structure
tar -cvf /path/to/tarfile.tar $(find . -type f ! -name '*.log')
```

This won't work if files have spaces though.

This may work if the filenames have spaces

```
cd /to/top/of/dir/structure
tar -cf /path/to/tarfile.tar --files-from /dev/null # trick to create empty tar file
find . -type f ! -name '*.log' -print0 | xargs -0 tar -uvf /path/to/tarfile.tar
```

Comment: Isn't there a command line length limit? If the number of files is very large, I think it might exceed that limit

Comment: @user49740: `xargs` takes care of that – it will split up the argument list to multiple `tar -uvf` invocations. (The maximum argument length is 32 pages on recent Linux kernels.)

Comment: Correction: s/argument length/argument+environment length/ and s/32 pages/¼ of the maximum stack size (ulimit -s)/ – my system shows ARG_MAX as 2 MB with the default ulimits.